# strip dashes or any special characters at the end of the string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I convert any special characters to dashes in my string except for alphanumerics using this:

```
return preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i", "-", $str);
```

However, in some case I have this strings:

```
$str = "Hello there chubby!";
```

which will result to:

```
Hello-there-chubby-
```

The dash on the end of word is what makes me think of a solution on how to remove that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
return trim(preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i", "-", $str), '-');
```

will strip leading and trailing dashes.

Answer (score 2):

You can try
`rtrim("Hello-there-chubby-", "-");`.

or

`preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9]+$#ims", "", "Hello-there-chubby-");`

for removing the last special character.